# Quotient groups and the first isomophism theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I've not found a duplicate but there's not much to go on. This is a question I have posed myself after thinking about a question in Sege Lang's "Undergraduate Algebra".

The matrices are over the field "F" not $\mathbb{R}$ but that shouldn't really matter.

Let $$X=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a && b \\ 0 && c\\\end{pmatrix} : a,c\ne 0 \right\}$$
$$Y=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1 && a \\ 0 && 1\\\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$
$$Z=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a && 0 \\ 0 && b\\\end{pmatrix} : a,b\ne 0\right\}$$

I am happy that these are subgroups of GL(2,F) (the group of 2x2 non-singular matrices in the field F)

I want to show that $Y$ (is a normal subgroup triangle) of X and that $\frac{X}{Y}$ is isomorphic to Z.

I want to use the first isomorphism theorem to prove the second part as it's basically in the right form, the subgroup part is sort of like a hint almost. I am not sure how to write it though, I feel it should be short but I can't do it in a confident and concise way.

Comment: See [The Not So Short Introduction to $\LaTeX\ 2_\varepsilon$](http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf), section 3.6.

Comment: @LuizCordeiro I got there, I was trying to include a package, turns out I had to use pmatrix. - I'm sure it'll come with practice, I hated LaTeX at first, but I'm getting better and faster with it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the homomorphism $X\rightarrow Z$ given by $\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\0 & c\end{bmatrix}\mapsto\begin{bmatrix}a & 0\\ 0 & c\end{bmatrix},$ whose kernel is $Y$, and apply the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: That's the bit I'm stuck on. I know what the theorem states but I've never actually used it or seen an example where it is used or used it. My main source is http://www.maths.tcd.ie/~dwilkins/Courses/311/311S1_0708.pdf and Rings Fields and Groups, you've kind of stopped at the bit I wanted to see done properly. (Page 14 in that PDF btw)

Comment: @AlecTeal Your source labels the theorems differently from what I'm used to.  What Luiz (and many others, including Lang, from where you take this problem) refer to as the "first isomorphism theorem" is just called "Corollary 1.20" in your source.  What your source calls "first isomorphism theorem" is what I would call the second isomorphism theorem, and what your source calls the second is what I would call the third isomorphism theorem.

Comment: I'd like to remind people about the showing normal subgroup part, I'd like to find a fast/easy way to do that. That done, that makes ... I'm not sure how can Z be the isomorphism? (The question this is derived from uses Lang's (and your) first.... I'm not quite sure what I've done) @Ted

Comment: @AlecTeal  The kernel of a homomorphism is always a normal subgroup.  For the rest of the problem, unless Lang's version of the first isomorphism theorem is somehow stated in a weird way, it's just a direct application of the theorem once you follow Luiz's hint above.

Comment: And it should look like Collary 1.20 @Ted? I was sure that it's 1st theorem was almost directly applicable, but it isn't?

Comment: @AlecTeal Yes, it should look like Corollary 1.20.  Corollary 1.20 directly solves your problem.  If it looks very different in Lang, please write out what you see in Lang...

Comment: @Ted are we looking at the same 1.20? How can $\theta(G)$ be $Z$? (And how can it be quickly shown that B is a normal subgroup of A)

Comment: @Ted I've managed to convince myself the other theorem 1 applies as it has an intersection (I have sets so I can do that) and a normal subgroup, where as the other one doesn't appear to be in a close form.

Comment: @AlecTeal It's definitely Corollary 1.20, not the other theorem.  In the notation of the corollary: $G$ is your $X$, $\theta$ is the homomorphism that Luiz gives above, and $K$ is your $Z$.  $\theta(G)$ means the image of the homomorphism.  You're right, you need to prove that the image of the homomorphism is $Z$, to apply the corollary.

Comment: @Ted then the image is clearly Z, that makes a lot more sense now. Is it significant that B is a normal subgroup of A (and once again, is there an easy way to show it? I want to find an easy way because this isn't iterating over a small and finite set, and as you can see in those notes I linked there are many potential ways of showing it.)

Comment: @AlecTeal There's no $B$ and $A$ in the problem; do you mean $Y$ and $X$?  The kernel of a homomorphism is always a normal subgroup.  So if you show that the kernel of the homomorphism from $X$ to $Z$ is $Y$, then you've proven that $Y$ is a normal subgroup of $X$.

Comment: Brilliant of course! Thanks @Ted I'd like to ask you one last question. I liked those notes I linked, they're very concise and I followed them, all the proofs, I enjoyed reading them, obviously it's not mathematically wrong (I followed the proofs) but if it is naming things wrongly should I stop reading it? It seems dangerous, what if I hadn't have noticed? (what if you hadn't have noticed from me linking it!)

Comment: @AlecTeal There is nothing wrong with that source and in fact, all the other terminology seems to be standard (from a quick glance).  It's more important to know what the theorems say than the labels.